# DI not working as expected

Tags: dependency-injection

I'm trying to get an instance of `Magento\Cms\Api\GetBlockByIdentifier`, however I am receiving a value of `null`.

I notice the CMS module defines a preference for this interface

```
vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml:13:
<preference for="Magento\Cms\Api\GetBlockByIdentifierInterface" type="Magento\Cms\Model\GetBlockByIdentifier" />
```

so I believe this is the correct way to go about getting an instance of `Magento\Cms\Api\GetBlockByIdentifier`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block\Product;

use
    Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView,
    Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface,
    Magento\Cms\Api\GetBlockByIdentifierInterface as BlockGetter,
    Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context as ElementContext;

class MyBlock extends AbstractView
{
    private
        $_oStoreManager,
        $_oBlockGetter;

    public function __constructor(
        StoreManagerInterface $oStoreManager,
        BlockGetter $oBlockGetter,
        ElementContext $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_oStoreManager = $oStoreManager;
        $this->_oBlockGetter  = $oBlockGetter;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Look on the product to see if there is a value in the
     * 'dynamic_block' attribute. If it is, use that value to search
     * for a static block with that as an identifier. If found, return the
     * markup from the static block. Otherwise return the empty string.
     */
    public function toHtml()
    {
        $staticBlockId = trim($this->getProduct()->getData('dynamic_block'));

        if($staticBlockId == '') {
            return '';
        }

        try {
            $storeId      = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            //----------------------------------------------------------
            /// XXX $this->_oBlockGetter is null ...
            $staticBlock  = $this->_oBlockGetter->execute($staticBlockId, $storeId);
            return $staticBlock->getContent();
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which magento version you are using I dont have this preference in my latest magento code ?

Comment: I'm using version 2.3

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to render static block in phtml you can simpley use following under the condition if product have cms block id save in attribute 'dynamic_block':

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a small typo on my part. If you check my code above you will see I am using `__constructor` instead of `__construct`! Too much es6 coding lately...